# How to get the number of empty dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list that is in this format `[['A', 'B'], {}, {}, {}]`i'm trying to get the number of empty dictionaries in the list what is the most pythonic way of doing this properly, i've been able to do it but i find myself having to create a temporary list in the process is there a more efficient way of doing this without creating a temporary list?

```
a = [['A', 'B'], {'test': 'lang'}, {}, {}]
tmp_list = list()

for i in a:
    if isinstance(i, dict):
        if len(i) == 0:
            tmp_list.append(i)

print(len(tmp_list))
```

Comment: Just have a count integer, and increment it.

Comment: As an aside, it is not idiomatic to have a list whose elements are not all of the same type.

Answer (score 5):

As Luke commented, just count it

```
a = [['A', 'B'], {'test': 'lang'}, {}, {}]
print(a.count({}))
```

Comment: Nice! I always forget about `.count`.

Comment: Haha, you should try to keep it in mind, it's very practical :D

Answer (score 3):

A [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) is handy here, along with the built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function:

```
a = [['A', 'B'], {'test': 'lang'}, {}, {}]
count = sum(1 for x in a if isinstance(x, dict) and not x)
print count
# 2
```

Also, you don't need to check `len` if you just want empty ones; since empty dictionaries evaluate as `False` in a boolean context, `not x` is sufficient.

Comment: I would use `x == {}`, since if someone has gone to all the trouble of implementing dict-compatible equality, they deserve it.

Comment: i'm still trying to wrap my head around the code, but is there any benefit of using generators to @Jean Araujo's answer

Comment: @danidee In this case, not really. The generator-expression version lets you do more complicated things (different conditions, different values, etc.) if you want to, but that's besides the point if all you need is a count of `{}`s.